# How to catch the errors of a child process using Python subprocess?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have the following Python(2.7) code:

```
try:    
  FNULL = open(os.devnull,'w')
  subprocess.check_call(["tar", "-czvf", '/folder/archive.tar.gz', '/folder/some_other_folder'], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except Exception as e:
  print str(e)
```

The problem which I face is that, when there is no more space for the archive, `print str(e)` prints `Command '['tar', '-czvf', '/folder/archive.tar.gz', '/folder/some_other_folder']' returned non-zero exit status 1`, which is true, but I want to catch the real error here, that is `gzip: write error: No space left on device` (I got the this error when I ran the same tar comand manually). Is that possible somehow? I assume that gzip is another process within tar. Am I wrong? Please keep in mind that upgrading to Python 3 is not possible.

EDIT: I also tried to use `subprocess.check_output()` and print the contents of `e.output` but that also didn't work

Comment: In general, "exit status 1" _is_ the only thing that's an actual unambiguous machine-readable error. stderr content can contain any diagnostic logging or human-readable informational content, not just errors -- so following the answer @ShadowRanger has written, while not _wrong_, can cause log messages that precede an error to be treated as if they're part of the error themselves.

Comment: ...so, f/e, when you write `if tar -czvf folder.archive.gz /folder; then ...; else echo "There was an error" >&2; fi` in shell, it's the exit status that the shell is relying on to know that something went wrong and follow the `else` branch.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: My answer only echoes `stderr` when the exit status is non-zero, so sure, you might see diagnostic output when an error occurs, but it'll be silent under normal (success) conditions. Definitely not relying on whether `stderr` is empty/non-empty.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, if you were checking empty/nonempty stderr you'd have a downvote; my position is rather one of cautious, qualified support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Python 3 solution for sane people

On Python 3, the solution is simple, and you should be using Python 3 for new code anyway (Python 2.7 ended all support nearly a year ago):

The problem is that the program is echoing the error to `stderr`, so `check_output` doesn't capture it (either normally, or in the `CalledProcessError`). The best solution is to use `subprocess.run` (which `check_call`/`check_output` are just a thin wrapper over) and ensure you capture both `stdout` and `stderr`. The simplest approach is:

```
try:
    subprocess.run(["tar", "-czvf", '/folder/archive.tar.gz', '/folder/some_other_folder'],
                   check=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                             # ^ Ignores stdout           ^ Captures stderr so e.stderr is populated if needed
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print("tar exited with exit status {}:".format(e.returncode), e.stderr, file=sys.stderr)
```

---

### Python 2 solution for people who like unsupported software

If you *must* do this on Python 2, you have to handle it all yourself by manually invoking `Popen`, as none of the high level functions available there will cover you (`CalledProcessError` didn't spawn a `stderr` attribute until 3.5, because no high-level API that raised it was designed to handle `stderr` at all):

```
with open(os.devnull, 'wb') as f:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["tar", "-czvf", '/folder/archive.tar.gz', '/folder/some_other_folder'],
                 stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    _, stderr = proc.communicate()
if proc.returncode != 0:
    # Assumes from __future__ import print_function at top of file
    # because Python 2 print statements are terrible
    print("tar exited with exit status {}:".format(proc.returncode), stderr, file=sys.stderr)
```